# How does the chip transactions happen throughout a hand on a live game?

Tags: live

Everyone has 100$ chips on their stack. Then 10/20$ blinds are posted. Where do these blinds physically stand as they are posted, in front of the stacks, or put in the main pot in the middle. Then once someone raises or calls, or goes all in, does the chips stay in front of the players, or in the main pot, or is there a timing before the dealer collects all the raises made in a hand and put in the main pot in a batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Players usually place their bets (including blinds) in front of their stack, but separated from it to make clear those aren't part of the stack anymore. Most tables in casinos will have lines separating the area for the players' stack and hidden cards from the area dedicated to the pot and community cards.

After each betting round, the dealer will pick all the chips and bring them to the center of the table, merging with the rest of the pot.

Answer (score 0):

proper procedure is for all bets to be left in front of the players stack it does not matter were in front of the player the bet is it simply needs to be clear that it is a bet and belongs to a particular player. after the bets are right, the dealer can pull them in, an often bad practice with many dealers is pulling in the bets before action is complete for a betting round, this can lead to a major CF if something is wrong and they need to recreate the betting sequence